# How do I set up a tezos node via command line on Ubuntu?

Tags: node, baking-node

I'm wondering if someone can give me start-to-finish on how to do this on Ubuntu, the Tezos Gitlab page is very outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here are the updated step-by-step instructions on how to build a Tezos node(fresh Ubuntu install)

#### become superuser

sudo su

#### update system

sudo su
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

#### install curl

sudo apt-get install curl

#### say yes to all prompts

#### install docker

sudo apt install docker.io
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker

#### install docker compose

sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo apt-get docker-compose

#### reply yes to all prompts

#### download the alphanet script

wget -O mainnet.sh https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/raw/master/scripts/alphanet.sh
chmod +x mainnet.sh

#### start mainnet

./mainnnet.sh start

(to update node later type:)
./mainnet.sh restart

#### update mainnet

./mainnet.sh update_script

### build from sources

#### all one line

sudo apt install -y rsync git m4 build-essential patch unzip bubblewrap wget pkg-config libgmp-dev libev-dev libhidapi-dev which wget https://github.com/ocaml/opam/releases/download/2.0.3/opam-2.0.3-x86_64-linux

sudo cp opam-2.0.3-x86_64-linux /usr/local/bin/opam
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/opam
git clone https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos.git
cd tezos
git checkout mainnet

#### type "yes" for opam init command

opam init --bare
make build-deps ## note: process 7 takes a long time
eval $(opam env)
make
export PATH=~/tezos:$PATH
source ./src/bin_client/bash-completion.sh
export TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER=Y

#### install jp

sudo apt install -y jq

#### install opam

make build-deps
make build-dev-deps ##takes a while
eval $(opam env)
make

#### generate tezos node ID ## if the tezos wasn't installed in /home/~, do a search for tezos

cd /home/'username'/tezos/

#### download node snapshot(saves you hours)

curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots/releases/latest | jq -r ".assets[] | select(.name) | .browser_download_url" | grep full | xargs wget -q --show-progress

#### find out the name of the file

ls /

#### unzip the file(only works with this command, otherwise file will be corrupted)

unxz "name of file"

#### rename the file, taking note of the block number, you will use it below(do this via Gui is fine)

#### create the tezos node identity, for the --block variable, use the block number located on the

./tezos-node identity generate

#### import the snapshot

./tezos-node snapshot import mainnet.full --block "exampleblockBMetLX2em7Q2tbAxcuPbUQNEY4NhRDEZtJCQeoFvWnYwDzb5qGU"

#### kill original app using the ports

sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8732)

#### start the node

./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1

### note use lsof command if file is locked and then killall to stop the process, or unlock the file by rm the lock file in the path

#### wait for node to sync(watch progress with this command

./tezos-client bootstrapped

### Your finished!!!

Comment: This is copied over from http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html, which is fine, but pls give credit to the source. And preferably fix the CRLFs.

Comment: https://medium.com/@tezbaker.io/tezos-mainnet-setting-up-home-baking-4bf258a9fd30

Answer (score 1):

[Tezster-CLI](https://github.com/Tezsure/Tezster-CLI) is the perfect tool to answer for your query. It will setup local nodes on your system in easy steps.

**Prerequisite:**
You must have installed docker and nodejs on your system.

To install docker run the following command: (on ubuntu)

```
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
```

**Install tezster-cli package:**

```
sudo npm install -g tezster@latest --unsafe-perm=true
```

**Setup local nodes:**

```
tezster setup
```

**Start and stop local nodes:**

```
tezster start-nodes
tezster stop-nodes
```

Use [Tezster-CLI Guide](https://docs.tezster.tech/tezster-cli) to learn more about tezster usage.